# current_path() inside theme_menu_link returns previous path

Tags: routes, theming, uri

I am trying to hide/show menu links based on my current page.  I have added the following snippet into my **template.php** file under **mytheme** folder.

```
/**
* Implements theme_menu_link().
*/
function mytheme_menu_link(array $variables) {
   $path = current_path();
   debug($path);
   //Do things based on $path

}
```

I have observed a very strange output of $path value. I will try to illustrator will a table

```
Time        |    Url          |   displayed $path value
   1        |    mysite/link1 |   none
   2        |    mysite/link2 |   link1
   3        |    mysite/link3 |   link2
```

It looks like the "current_path()" function call inside my mytheme_menu_link always returns the **previous path**. I have spent a full day googling and didn't see any case that is similar to mine.

Can someone tell me what is the possible cause and how I can avoid it?

Thanks!

PS: I have another call for current_path() inside **mymodule_block_list_alter** function and that one works correctly.

Comment: Are you sure it is not caused by the way `debug()` works in your setup? Have you tested this with [`kpr()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/kpr/7) for example?

Comment: I don't think debug() caused the error. Because it printed correctly in other pages. I am thinking it could be by the time theme_menu_link is called, the url has not changed yet.

Comment: Do you even know for sure which request generated which message?

Comment: yes, I put the debug() in both files. and I was able to see that the one in template.php get called before the one in module file.

Comment: Well, when "url changed", it's next http request. So if [you are unsure if it changed, or not yet](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/111080/current-path-inside-theme-menu-link-returns-previous-path?noredirect=1#comment132887_111080), then you don't know what happens in what request.